# Flutter flavors and navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes

How is routing usually handled between the main flutter app and the 'flavored' screens or widgets?

For example, I have a custom router defined in the main flutter app, and if I try to use it in 'flavored' parts of the app, I cannot.

`.pushNamed` function doesn't work, it always says "**unknown route**". On the other hand, `.push` works, so I assume there is some problem with the scope of the `Navigator` maybe?

I don't know how named routes are usually handled when dealing with flutter flavors. Any idea would be most appreciated!